# jQuery replace function (trigger needed)

Tags: php, jquery, html, regex

i got a jQuery function to check a textarea for "valid" urls while someone is typing.

```
$(".url2").keyup(validNum).blur(validNum);

function validNum() {

var initVal = $(this).val();
outputVal = initVal.replace(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])$/,"replace this link by bla..");   
if (initVal != outputVal) {
    $(this).val(outputVal);

    }}
```

});

problem is, that the functions already replaces the url as soon as "http://www.ab" is typed instead of waiting till space is pressed (complete url, waitig for space, replace with this function). I want to achieve, that people can type in a whole url like http://www.example.org/site?id=1&etcetc before it gets replaced. So I think of "space" as a trigger to start the function. Can someone help me or someone got a better idea?

Thank you so much

wordi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want space or whitespace chars to trigger validation, use this:

```
  $(".url2").keyup(validateOnWhiteSpace).blur(validNum);

  function validateOnWhiteSpace() {
    if(event.keyCode == 9 ||  event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 32) {
        validNum.call(this, arguments);
    }
  }

function validNum() {

var initVal = $(this).val();
outputVal = initVal.replace(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])$/,"replace this link by bla..");   
if (initVal != outputVal) {
    $(this).val(outputVal);

    }}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just change your regex you will get what you want

```
/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])(\s){1}$/
```

[Here is a jsfiddle that seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/NullRef/UJcmj/)

Comment: thank you very much, it works :) but another question, i had another regex pattern before, but it doesn't seem to work with jquery while it works perfectly with php. /^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?+(www.)?+[0-9A-Za-z-]{2,50}+[.]{1,1}+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}+[\/]{0,1}+[\/\%\:a-zA-Z0-9.=?&_-]{0,250}$/ Does anyone see the problem in this pattern?!

Comment: Glad the above works. I would open another question for this next one but I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I can't yet comment on the first thread, but to answer your question about the PHP regexp not working in jQuery, it is because you have ^ at the beginning and $ at the end.  The ^ matches the beginning of the string and $ matches the end of the string.  Taking it out will allow the regexp to match at any point in the string.

Example:

^abc\d$

Will match:

"abc1"

Will NOT match:

"Zabc1"

Since the "a" is not the first character of the string.

Comment: heyo thanks I understand that, the above RegEX from NullRef is working fine, but mine isn't even without ^ and $ ;(

Comment: Try this maybe:

/(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?[0-9A-Za-z-]{2,50}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}\/?[\/\%\:a-zA-Z0-9.=?&_-]{0,250}/

You're adding + symbols after {#,#} which doesn't really make sense and is invalid syntax.

Comment: Or /(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?[0-9A-Za-z-]{2,50}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}[^\s]{0,250}/ would be even simpler...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".url2").onchange(validNum).blur(validNum);

function validNum() {

     var initVal = $(this).val();
    outputVal = initVal.replace(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])$/,"replace this link by bla..");   
    if (initVal != outputVal) {
        $(this).val(outputVal);
    }
}
```